# Failure to connect to SQL Server via R (RODBC package)

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I have spent a fair amount of time trying to connect to our SQL Server using `RODBC` package. Initially, the package was complaining that it wouldn't run unless I have R version 4.0. So I did update my R. Now I have tried multiple combinations of connection specifications and none of them seem to work. Could anybody provide a comprehensive walk-through on this?

```
con = odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver = {SQL Server}; Server = XYZ;
                        Database = ABC; trusted_connection = yes")
```

or

```
con = odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver = {SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server = XYZ;
                            Database = ABC; trusted_connection = yes")
```

Does this connection method support Windows Authentication? Or do I need to specify `uid` and `pwd` as well? I have only been using Windows Authentication to get data from our databases.

The error that I keep getting is `ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found`.

Comment: Do you have a data source name defined on the machine where you are calling from?

Comment: I am not sure, where can I see this? I think its under DSN, for which I am getting `you are logged on with non-Administrative privileges ...`

Comment: On Windows 10 (which I assume you're using) you should be able to run `odbcad32.exe` to create your own DSNs. I can't test it since I don't happen to have a SQL Server instance I can connect to.